# Xcode 12.4 keeps loading..100% cpu m1

Tags: apple-m1

I have tried all the solution I could find in the internet except that I was unable to set connect via  network cuz when ever I start Xcode it will keep loading and not respond. I am using Xcode 12.4. CPU usage is showing 100%. Any solution?
I am using MacBook Pro m1 13".

Comment: sounds like a question for apple. Submit a help request or a bug report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After downgrading back to 12.3 its working well as before